# How to play these chords?

Tags: guitar, technique, notation, tablature

I'm trying to play ["Sweet Home Alabama"](http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/l/lynyrd_skynyrd/sweet_home_alabama_intro_tab.htm#comments). What confuses me is when I see things like `0h2p0` and `0h2(x4)`. What are those, and how do you play them?

Comment: [This](http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/l/lynyrd_skynyrd/sweet_home_alabama_tab.htm) tab seems to be a better fit for that song, but you'll still need the answer to this question.

Answer (score 8):

It means that you have to hit the string in the 2nd fret wirh your finger and then raise it inmediately, I mean, h = hammer on (hit the string) p = pull off (raise the finger). Watch this video about hammer on and pull off http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5sXDHVl0R0

Edit:

This one is better http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hN9zZd07Kio&feature=fvwrel

Comment: @Ruben you can edit your answers and add additional information to them if you need to. No need to answer a question twice.

Answer (score 3):

Quick tip for the pull off technique.  Dont just let go or raise the finger you are pulling off with or the note will you pull off to will be quiet or may not sound.  You need to pull your finger down slightly when you pull off (away from the neck and slightly towards the floor) so the finger almost picks the string as it pulls off producing a clearer note.  If you watch the video closely you will see the tutor is doing this or if you like try this video http://www.justinguitar.com/en/IM-154-LegatoScales.php for a clearer explanation

Answer (score 2):

These h and p indicade a legate passage, that means you play the notes without hitting the string with pick.

h stands for hammer on, and
p stands for pull of

for example you have - 0h2 - To play this you need to pick your string and then hammer on the second fret to let the second note ring. - 4p2 is the other way around, pick the string while hold the fourth fret and then pull off from the string (in a gentle downwards motion) to let the note of the second fret ring.

This might require some practice first, but you'll get used to it soon.

Have fun :D